# PowerShell/Unrar - Use securestring with Unrar Password switch

Tags: powershell, rar, winrar, unrar

I have a configuration file with secure strings. These strings are passwords I use for automation.

Typically, I can encrypt my passwords with

```
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

A prompt comes up for me to type in the password, and it outputs the secure string. I store these secure strings in the configuration file.

I can query these secure strings into a powershell script like so:

```
SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Config.Configuration.password
```

This works for my WinSCP application, so I do not have credentials stored in plain text within my configuration file.

My problem:

I am trying to do something similar with WinRAR's Unrar utility. The following plain text example works:

```
$PW = "mypassword"
& $unrar_path x $Source_Path.exe -p"$PW" $Destination_Path\
```

If I attempt to query the secure string from the configuration file:

```
$PW = ConvertTo-SecureString $Config.Configuration.ExtractPass
& $unrar_path x $Source_Path.exe -p"$PW" $Destination_Path\
```

It does not accept the password.

I have tried a lot of different syntax versions attempting to get the secure string to work. Is there another approach to this I am not figuring out?

Any help or suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRAR won't take a secure string as argument, it has no concept of it, if you start from a secure string and want to pass the plain text password as argument you will need to decrypt it, either with [`ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.4#-asplaintext) (`powershell 7+`) or [`NetworkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=net-8.0) (`powershell 5.1`).

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $Config.Configuration.ExtractPass
$plainTextPassw = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $secureString).Password
& $unrar_path x $Source_Path.exe -p $plainTextPassw $Destination_Path\
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. This helped me realized I am using PS 5.1.
Does this mean I need to encrypt the password in a different way than the 'Read-Host' example above? I'm struggling a bit trying to decrypt the password from the secure string as I have it now in the configuration file (with the method you have showed me).

Comment: @CliffordPiehl `$Config.Configuration.ExtractPass` is a encrypted string? if so, then you need to convert the encrypted string into a `SecureString` just as shown in the answer, then from `SecureString` into plain text the code in this answer would handle it

Comment: @CliffordPiehl glad it did, happy to help :)

Comment: Though beware that password passed on commandline can be seen in the task manager and can be read by any other process on running on the machine.

Comment: Better would be using the environment variable `RAR` defined with `-p $plainTextPassw` inside the PowerShell script before running `unrar.exe` and undefine this environment variable immediately after `unrar.exe` execution finished. That does not mean that no other process can find out the plain text password while `unrar.exe` is running, but it becomes at least a bit more difficult.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Is this an intrinsic risk when automating tasks on the operating system? Or is there another way?

Comment: Many tools allow other methods to pass a password (at least using a file, instead of command line, but even better using named pipe). It does not look like `unrar` does though.